# Why can't I create a Color in Java with "new" keyword?

Tags: java, colors, constructor, awt

I was trying to make a new color in java using

```
Color temp = new Color(foo.getBackground());
```

and it kept telling me cannot find symbol.

But this works

```
Color temp = (foo.getbackground());
```

Why?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That's because `foo.getBackground()` returns a `Color` instance, and there's no `Color` constructor which takes a `Color` instance as an argument.

Comment: if you want to make a copy of foo's color, you can do this: `Color tmp = new Color(foo.getBackground().getRGB());`

Comment: Though there's not much point, as Color instances are immutable.

Comment: Indeed, and I suspect that kokokok really just wants to say
`Color temp = foo.getBackground();`

Answer (score 5):

Check this link [Color (Java 2 Platform SE v1.4.2)](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html).

If you want this code to work:

```
Color temp = new Color(foo.getBackground());
```

foo.getBackground() must return an integer. Since it returns an object Color you have type mismatch.

You can always do:

```
Color temp = new Color(foo.getbackground().getRGB());
```

or:

```
Color color = foo.getBackground();
Color temp = new Color(color.getRed(), color.getGreen(), color.getBlue(),color.getAlpha());
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it, the problem is that maybe foo.getBackground does'nt returns an integer or something similar.

```
Color c = new Color(23,32,43)
```

works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a constructor for Color that takes just a Color. In the second instance you're assigning a variable that was returned from a function.

Answer (score 0):

The Color class does not have a constructor taking an other instance of Color as an argument, and that is what foo.getBackground() returns. IIRC, the Color class in Java is immutable - so there is simply no point in providing a constructor that would create a copy of an existing Color object.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the type that foo.getBackground() returns is of type "Color".

While you can of course assign a Color to the variable temp of type Color, at least in java.awt.Color there is not constructor to create a Color from another Color.